# Is show waveform always referring to current?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, waveform

In EveryCircuit, it allows you to "show waveform" for a particular component. For example:

[image]

Does waveform **always** refer to the current that is going through that component or are there ever alternate waveform-types?

Comment: Current is about the only thing that goes "through" a component. Voltage is measured across two points, or between two points but does not go through anything.

Comment: @DKNguyen how would you view that in EveryCircuit?

Comment: Never used EveryCircuit so I don't know. But try right clicking in places. Voltage plots should definitely be in there somewhere.